# jquery val().length causing error in ie7

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-7

In the following line I am getting error "Object Doesn't support this property or method" in IE7.

```
if($("#"+id+"_txt").val().length > 0)
{
    ...........
}
```

Anybody know what the problem is?

Thanks

Comment: What's causing the error? Is it the `.val()` or the `.length`?

Comment: Show us the html for element ("#"+id+"_txt") you are trying to access...

Comment: why are you adding `"_txt"`?

Comment: `val` might be returning `null`. Separate your code and debug it step by step.

Comment: Add some code.I don,t think val().length is causing the problem..

Answer (score 0):

```
var id='';
id= $("#"+id+"_txt").val();
if(id.length > 0)
{
   //do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// this make sure val is not null and length > 0
if($("#"+id+"_txt").val())
{
    ...........
}
```

You can run a quick test to confirm.

```
if (""){
    alert('emptied: true;')
}
else {
    alert('emptied: false;')
}

if (null){
    alert('null: true;')
}
else {
    alert('null: false;')
}
```